# Keras Conv1D to CoreML not behaving as expected

Tags: neural-network, keras, coreml

I build a model in Keras as follows:

```python
sequence_length = 300
num_cats = 64

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv1D(filters=4,
                 kernel_size=4,
                 strides=4, 
                 padding='same', 
                 activation='relu',
                 input_shape=(sequence_length, 1),
                 name='input'))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(num_cats, activation='softmax'))

for (i, layer) in enumerate(model.layers):
    print(i, type(layer), layer.input_shape, layer.output_shape)

model.compile(loss=keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy,
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.002, decay=1e-6),#0.004
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

The shape of the layers of this model are as follows:

```python
0 <class 'keras.layers.convolutional.Conv1D'> (None, 300, 1) (None, 75, 4)
1 <class 'keras.layers.core.Dense'> (None, 75, 4) (None, 75, 32)
2 <class 'keras.layers.core.Dense'> (None, 75, 32) (None, 75, 64)
```

So the model should accept an arbitrary number of sequences of size 300x1 and return the same number of sequences of size 75x64. This works well with keras when using `model.predict`.

Converting to CoreML appears to work:

```python
>>> coreml_model = coremltools.converters.keras.convert(model_name,
                                                        input_names=['input1'])

0 : input_input, <keras.engine.topology.InputLayer object at 0x11d1aae48>
1 : input_input_permute_input, <keras.layers.core.Permute object at 0x11d08f668>
2 : input, <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv1D object at 0x11d1aab38>
3 : input__activation__, <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x11d08fef0>
4 : input_permute_dense_3, <keras.layers.core.Permute object at 0x11cdf8748>
5 : dense_3, <keras.layers.core.Dense object at 0x11d1aae80>
6 : dense_3__activation__, <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x11cd33320>
7 : dense_4, <keras.layers.core.Dense object at 0x11d1c82e8>
8 : dense_4__activation__, <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x11cd33198>
```

However something goes wrong when trying to run a prediction:

```python
>>> coreml_model.predict({'input1': [0.0 for _ in range(300)]})

RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-fa8bb7c37555> in <module>()
      1 inputX = X[0:3]#.reshape(-1,1,1000)
      2 print(inputX.shape)
----> 3 coreml_model.predict({'input1': [0.0 for _ in range(300)]})

~/dev/coreml_experiments/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/coremltools/models/model.py in predict(self, data, useCPUOnly, **kwargs)
    262 
    263         if self.__proxy__:
--> 264             return self.__proxy__.predict(data,useCPUOnly)
    265         else:
    266             if _macos_version() < (10, 13):

RuntimeError: {
    NSLocalizedDescription = "Input feature input1 was presented as a vector of length 300, but the model expects an input of length 1.";
}
```

Indeed the only thing that does work is an array of length 1:

```python
coreml_model.predict({'input1': [0.0]})
```

Which returns an array of length 64 but really ought to cause an error. What is going wrong with the conversion or my understanding of it?

Comment: Shouldn't your input be of shape `(1, 300, 1)`? Right now your input is of shape `(300)`, i.e. it misses two dimensions.

Comment: @MatthijsHollemans this causes a very strange error and termination of the program:

[1]    63795 abort      python test.py

Comment: @MatthijsHollemans what is more if I reduce the size of the sequence from 300 to 16 and use and input of shape `(1,16,1)` then it doesn't crash but the output has shape `(16,64)` but this makes no sense at all because with a stride of 4 it should be `(4,16)` so I think it is interpreting `(1,300,1)` as 300 sequences of length 1.

Comment: I haven't really tried Core ML with sequences yet, but the internal representation that it uses for data is `sequence_length, batch_size, channels, height, width` so maybe try a shape of `(300, 1, 1, 1, 1)`? I'm totally guessing here.

Comment: Hi @MatthijsHollemans so it seems that sequences with CoreML + Keras are pretty confusing/buggy. I am discussing this with the CoreML developers here: https://github.com/apple/coremltools/issues/142